# unique row id for each submit button in php

Tags: php, html

I am having multiple submit buttons.

and in a row i have 2 select options and a submit button.

how to generate unique rowid for each submit button 
want to make each submit and select options unique and post it to the next page

Comment: no code = no question

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows with row id if you have...

```
<input type="submit" id="button_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="button_submit"/>
```

And if not then you can use it through loop... and set id as "button_"/>

Comment: and what will be id for my select options? i also want to make it unique and post it to the next page

Comment: If you are getting it from database then use the column means id.

Answer (score -1):

```
             <tr>
             <th>S.NO</th>
            <th>Proposed Action</th>
             <th>Submitted/Return To</th>
             <th>Click</th>
             </tr>

     <?php 

     $sno=1;



print"  <tbody>
             <tr>

          <td>  <select name='select2' class='selectpicker' id='select2'>
                   <option value='-2'>a</option>
                  <option value='99'>p</option>

              <option value='88'>c</option>
           <option value='77'>d</option>
            <option value='66'>v</option> </select> </td>



               <td>  <select name='select' class='selectpicker' id='select' >
                   <option value='0'><------select------></option>



              <option value='4'>apple</option>

            <option value='5'>mango</option>
             <option value='6'>berry</option>


        </select> </td>";?>
    <?php    print"  



              <td><input type='submit' name='forward$sno' value='forward'></td>   
             </tr>
              </tbody>";
 $sno++;
```

}?>

```
             </table>
        </form>
```